# Why lm summary isn't showing all the interceptions between factors?

Tags: r, anova

I'm a newbie in `R` and I'm trying to make an anova calculation using lm, after that I'd like to see the result with all the interceptions between factors in columns.

## The Problem

In this experiment we have 3 methods (`Percentile`, `Octave`, `Hz`) in which we'll test the human behaviour in relation to a different noise frequency (`low`,`high`,`silence`).

### The Model

I'm using a CSV formatted like this

```
Methods;Noise;Hz
Percentile;high;183.331304332118
Percentile;high;188.700251524734
Percentile;high;187.981406253728
Percentile;high;183.063549230495
Percentile;high;181.275344044304
Percentile;high;186.390073815347
Percentile;high;185.276936827262
Percentile;high;189.451214942605
Percentile;high;183.880082107861
Percentile;high;182.797552600182
Percentile;high;190.690402980126
Percentile;high;195.560657798661
Percentile;high;199.755132769633
Percentile;high;193.530728938511
Percentile;high;189.415576920898
Percentile;high;191.953409683289
Percentile;high;182.677411105465
Percentile;high;179.967713041086
Percentile;high;178.773203738534
Percentile;high;187.940291319059
Percentile;high;188.37198629427
Percentile;high;190.804261704368
Percentile;high;188.204944591967
Percentile;high;189.878728456049
Percentile;high;192.173217154293
Percentile;high;196.242760984352
Percentile;high;188.50639006309
Percentile;high;187.592306471642
Percentile;high;189.504218468955
Percentile;high;189.406948200963
Percentile;low;184.071313381331
Percentile;low;186.549994445228
Percentile;low;187.612904801172
Percentile;low;179.545664178984
Percentile;low;185.501452134986
Percentile;low;183.04813334516
Percentile;low;185.272590641012
Percentile;low;188.223790534832
Percentile;low;191.53890249587
Percentile;low;189.897486796666
Percentile;low;186.976025784438
Percentile;low;201.01009850096
Percentile;low;189.671054700772
Percentile;low;191.517156609792
Percentile;low;191.974627190161
Percentile;low;183.60528784224
Percentile;low;189.489467495134
Percentile;low;187.59118720584
Percentile;low;179.148376572124
Percentile;low;190.213262287936
Percentile;low;190.547912861763
Percentile;low;191.31674781661
Percentile;low;190.500467436005
Percentile;low;192.005581807946
Percentile;low;198.30347482902
Percentile;low;188.774888844154
Percentile;low;188.616074928729
Percentile;low;188.768266897872
Percentile;low;187.952255840268
Percentile;low;187.102612653631
Percentile;silence;190.104781664582
Percentile;silence;183.680256921886
Percentile;silence;182.657500193922
Percentile;silence;188.419130497428
Percentile;silence;186.043762271612
Percentile;silence;186.219404010971
Percentile;silence;182.610484383669
Percentile;silence;180.131064641956
Percentile;silence;186.316305260538
Percentile;silence;189.918111107452
Percentile;silence;188.000000000000
Percentile;silence;185.008741027017
Percentile;silence;184.993240395746
Percentile;silence;195.472457419513
Percentile;silence;194.344230774805
Percentile;silence;184.777079106968
Percentile;silence;179.965496355367
Percentile;silence;185.853193034801
Percentile;silence;174.910375823091
Percentile;silence;186.662625379489
Percentile;silence;185.905317471047
Percentile;silence;193.665403366482
Percentile;silence;190.556835877246
Percentile;silence;189.120161764536
Percentile;silence;186.879814490783
Percentile;silence;187.93998719181
Percentile;silence;187.424001915415
Percentile;silence;184.095336225304
Percentile;silence;185.448512575268
Percentile;silence;190.152157042459
Octave ;high;191.9609210145
Octave ;high;193.227608643392
Octave ;high;192.119552445754
Octave ;high;184.204587424205
Octave ;high;193.349530301129
Octave ;high;197.606531028181
Octave ;high;192.682256157472
Octave ;high;217.712310214031
Octave ;high;196.265095806444
Octave ;high;192.525086348611
Octave ;high;189.341489947479
Octave ;high;190.293301510175
Octave ;high;192.080359393156
Octave ;high;194.518250846081
Octave ;high;193.717176026784
Octave ;high;187.547460325335
Octave ;high;192.649159412471
Octave ;high;191.277694680385
Octave ;high;185.478509649549
Octave ;high;192.762752389247
Octave ;high;189.628687344797
Octave ;high;189.956496674298
Octave ;high;189.252420198778
Octave ;high;194.528933323126
Octave ;high;187.721453083967
Octave ;high;188.834930801539
Octave ;high;193.341764942198
Octave ;high;197.439732703603
Octave ;high;196.872856136756
Octave ;high;194.3767843157
Octave ;low;195.304024063053
Octave ;low;192.641392287249
Octave ;low;187.63227349659
Octave ;low;200.545615854295
Octave ;low;193.965904099208
Octave ;low;193.070707443664
Octave ;low;194.686666169746
Octave ;low;193.727478175816
Octave ;low;198.136600180433
Octave ;low;188.352488251745
Octave ;low;191.841817740992
Octave ;low;191.943649095057
Octave ;low;196.036774846345
Octave ;low;194.123767824746
Octave ;low;191.682879096004
Octave ;low;188.772812912477
Octave ;low;195.028623700436
Octave ;low;192.680993745817
Octave ;low;189.209710689711
Octave ;low;189.859800000011
Octave ;low;187.769269002402
Octave ;low;188.561505887661
Octave ;low;187.915147846494
Octave ;low;185.54090612456
Octave ;low;189.436664418332
Octave ;low;192.418614088337
Octave ;low;192.970537630881
Octave ;low;193.656884338111
Octave ;low;200.310751120313
Octave ;low;198.867230360347
Octave ;silence;190.761532437208
Octave ;silence;193.550357140814
Octave ;silence;192.201601354056
Octave ;silence;191.597930920003
Octave ;silence;195.32630952257
Octave ;silence;195.087006707302
Octave ;silence;196.078316446006
Octave ;silence;196.348049156772
Octave ;silence;190.280284425736
Octave ;silence;193.67863362259
Octave ;silence;190.267175417627
Octave ;silence;194.626580077594
Octave ;silence;190.100126592442
Octave ;silence;193.479856856941
Octave ;silence;192.360185319116
Octave ;silence;192.354215911275
Octave ;silence;189.675774375019
Octave ;silence;193.839192512052
Octave ;silence;195.030147742873
Octave ;silence;187.277143372822
Octave ;silence;192.074083745447
Octave ;silence;189.699151861476
Octave ;silence;189.852343460182
Octave ;silence;190.759887832771
Octave ;silence;184.739721117801
Octave ;silence;187.318111492213
Octave ;silence;188.537859208897
Octave ;silence;197.40192413607
Octave ;silence;198.225776265921
Octave ;silence;197.022934158398
Hertz;high;186.263432857971
Hertz;high;189.519603604846
Hertz;high;188.888364675763
Hertz;high;191.909175272676
Hertz;high;194.887206345445
Hertz;high;192.453811602492
Hertz;high;193.891669262421
Hertz;high;194.123714713959
Hertz;high;192.09091346517
Hertz;high;192.237460503099
Hertz;high;192.237532961733
Hertz;high;192.107779572611
Hertz;high;197.760987431519
Hertz;high;195.906189832613
Hertz;high;193.751838593716
Hertz;high;189.980461860985
Hertz;high;188.430523680666
Hertz;high;190.487303671203
Hertz;high;194.662474387386
Hertz;high;192.138030631885
Hertz;high;196.888058531005
Hertz;high;194.889061427512
Hertz;high;192.096502551729
Hertz;high;196.031098985445
Hertz;high;195.629403790834
Hertz;high;193.304172348214
Hertz;high;196.952549494718
Hertz;high;199.678208657899
Hertz;high;195.62280879468
Hertz;high;194.423464502011
Hertz;low;190.395874467327
Hertz;low;192.335897366552
Hertz;low;186.873237285217
Hertz;low;190.617072161564
Hertz;low;190.261944771911
Hertz;low;191.262979381732
Hertz;low;195.775210087157
Hertz;low;187.088297648944
Hertz;low;193.585589222383
Hertz;low;191.258117398035
Hertz;low;191.214611947674
Hertz;low;193.500713935197
Hertz;low;192.829864570447
Hertz;low;193.562657483201
Hertz;low;194.092423514947
Hertz;low;191.293739497492
Hertz;low;189.768260415863
Hertz;low;193.829147503738
Hertz;low;191.73957510167
Hertz;low;195.003963890834
Hertz;low;193.435279044114
Hertz;low;195.841682073945
Hertz;low;191.665344087895
Hertz;low;188.464542851864
Hertz;low;190.787865419373
Hertz;low;197.229119727787
Hertz;low;192.197913349046
Hertz;low;196.785840009065
Hertz;low;199.749719012396
Hertz;low;195.585983287981
Hertz;silence;191.68112645566
Hertz;silence;190.253416057258
Hertz;silence;188.578794398102
Hertz;silence;192.397251769285
Hertz;silence;196.500102959722
Hertz;silence;188.785191385635
Hertz;silence;186.846185233126
Hertz;silence;190.2139443274
Hertz;silence;194.160741832248
Hertz;silence;194.109746826997
Hertz;silence;193.339677268904
Hertz;silence;192.580391901221
Hertz;silence;199.721183774143
Hertz;silence;193.925710289066
Hertz;silence;198.883163972756
Hertz;silence;184.325278822806
Hertz;silence;190.408492909811
Hertz;silence;186.753712011544
Hertz;silence;192.139294651804
Hertz;silence;194.285081016374
Hertz;silence;198.341439392388
Hertz;silence;195.563971630709
Hertz;silence;198.127119457316
Hertz;silence;194.394561813993
Hertz;silence;193.634325330551
Hertz;silence;195.364458535246
Hertz;silence;205.261948891476
Hertz;silence;201.861557936696
Hertz;silence;197.233267477103
Hertz;silence;191.634368517746
```

### The Script

```
# 3x3.R
# import the data
data <- read.csv(file = "3x3.csv",sep = ";")

# make method and noise factors
data$Method <- as.factor(data$Method)
data$Noise <- as.factor(data$Noise)
# and after checking assumptions:

# old function call with aov
# model <- aov(Hz ~ Method + Noise, data = data)
# summary(model)

lm.model <- lm(Hz ~ Method + Noise, data = data)
summary(lm.model)
```

### The output

```
macbook:anova user$ Rscript 3x3.R 

Call:
lm(formula = Hz ~ Method + Noise, data = data)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-12.5331  -2.5277  -0.0034   2.2819  24.9324 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      193.4362     0.5723 337.996  < 2e-16 ***
MethodOctave      -0.6563     0.6269  -1.047    0.296    
MethodPercentile  -5.4651     0.6269  -8.717 3.18e-16 ***
Noiselow          -0.1616     0.6269  -0.258    0.797    
Noisesilence      -0.5276     0.6269  -0.842    0.401    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.206 on 265 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2564,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2451 
F-statistic: 22.84 on 4 and 265 DF,  p-value: 3.152e-16
```

Can't understand why the interceptions Noisehigh and MethodHz are missing.

Thank you for the attention (:

Comment: They are used as reference levels and included in the intercept. If you're not happy with these, which are used because they appear first in alphabet, you could e.g. use `Hz ~ relevel(method, ref='Octave') + relevel(Noise, ref='low')` as formula.

Comment: I changed the `lm` line in:
```lm.model <- lm(Hz ~ relevel(Method, ref='Octave') + relevel(Noise, ref='low'), data = data)
```

but now there's an error:

```Error in relevel.factor(Method, ref = "Octave") : 
  'ref' must be an existing level
Calls: lm ... model.frame.default -> eval -> eval -> relevel -> relevel.factor
Execution halted
```

Comment: Try `relevel(Method, ref='Octave ')` (space added), looks like you have a space in your .csv. Or do `data$Method <- as.factor(trimws(data$Method))`.